How to transfer Streamlit app ownership in Snowflake?
I have some Streamlit apps in Snowflake.
I hope to transfer a Streamlit app my_streamlit_app from role OLD_ROLE to NEW_ROLE.

I found this discussion. However, I do not have that "dot menu" option in my UI.
What would be SQL or any way through UI to transfer ownership to another new role?
Thanks!

Got an answer from Snowflake team Jon Alkan and thanks!

Unfortunately, transferring ownership of a Streamlit application is not possible, but is on our radar and is in the works for the coming quarters. Currently, you would have to recreate the application with the new role as the owner.

